# Compile, Provided, APK - Android dependency scope

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

While adding new dependencies to android project especially in `Android Studio` in `Dependencies`  there are three scope options Compile/Provided/APK.

What are the effects of choosing each one, when should we use them ? Besides what the name says.

EDIT:

"Properly handle 'provided' and 'package' scopes to do what they should be doing.
'provided' and 'package' cannot be used with Android Libraries, and will generate an error" .. this is from http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

Comment: To clarify my currently-open bounty, if you use the Project Structure dialog in Android Studio to work with dependencies, there is a "Scope" drop-down. Most items in that drop-down make sense. One that does not is "APK". If you choose it, you wind up with something like `dependencies { apk 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0' }` in `build.gradle`. However, it is unclear what this scope actually means, in terms of what will be done with the dependency.

Answer (score 42):

- `provided` - compile-time only dependency
- `package` - package-time only dependency
- `compile` - compile-time and package-time dependency

`provided` is commonly used for annotation processing based libraries. Usually these libraries are separated in two artifacts - "annotation" and "compiler". "compiler" is `provided` dependency because you do not need to use it in application, only for compilation; and "annotation" is `compile` dependency - it is used in application code and therefore compiles. Or generated code may require additional dependencies while your application may not. E.g. dagger dependencies configuration:

```
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
```

Comment: So in android we need to declare this for dagger to work:                 provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'  so does that mean the device will not have this code, its only for compile time then the methods/classes are no longer included in device ?

Comment: can you explain a little what package time only dependency is ? Are you sure its still used ?

Comment: @j2emanue yes only for package time. This particular dependency is required for annotation processor to generate the result classes as far as I remember. It won't be packaged in output apk.

Answer (score 36):

These properties come from [`maven` scopes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

They simply indicate how to treat particular dependencies during each step of build process.

1. `compile` - a default approach, it simply means that all dependencies should be available at compile-time. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project. Furthermore, those dependencies are propagated to dependent projects. A compile-time dependency is generally required at runtime.
2. `package` -  declares additional configuration for building an application. You can list plugins that add additional functionality to the build process.
3. `provided` - it means that runtime environment has these dependencies included. For example, when you look into `android.jar` library internals you will see `java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!` in every method body.

   That has some consequences:

   - You can develop Android applications locally, without having complete Android environment.
   - Your APK you must run it on an android device or an emulator because they *provide* implementation of these methods.
   - Your apps that reference the SDK classes will build properly, because the jar provides the class metadata.
   - Unless you use some library that provides artifacts (e.g. [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/)), you have to run tests on your emulator/device.

`provided` and `package` cannot be used with Android Libraries, and will generate an error.

Here is how `sourceSet` looks like:

[image]

More info about build system: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCJAgPkpmR0

An awesome article about Gradle: http://www.sinking.in/blog/provided-scope-in-gradle/

Answer (score 16):

Xavier talks [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adt-dev/WIjtHjgoGwA/7FRP-CuxMdAJ) about the **APK** scope.

> in the Android plugin, The equivalent (sort of) of runtime is called apk. You can do
>
> dependencies {
>      apk files('libs/foo.jar')
>   }
>
> and it'll only get packaged but won't be on the compile classpath.

Comment: That appears to be it. I am somewhat befuddled why anyone would want this, but perhaps I'm just not being creative enough. Many thanks!

Comment: Just guessing here, but you might want a different jar for each of your flavors (for example, for different architectures)?

Comment: You would use `flavor1Compile`, `flavor2Compile`, etc. for those (where `flavor1` and `flavor2` are your flavors).

Comment: The only scenario I can think of is having some kind of stub to compile to with a different implementation at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

With gradle 6.5.1 `provided` gives the below error

```
Could not find method provided() for arguments [directory '....'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I used `compileOnly` to use the dependencies at only compile time and not to inlcude in the final build artifact