# Should I move some dependencies to `runtime` in Gradle in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, lint

Using [gradle-lint-plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-lint-plugin) in Android Studio, it hints that

```
:lintGradle

This project contains lint violations. A complete listing of the
violations follows.  Because none were serious, the build's overall
status was unaffected.

this dependency should be moved to the runtime configuration since it
has no classes warning   unused-dependency                 
app/build.gradle:43 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0'

this dependency should be moved to the runtime configuration since it
has no classes warning   unused-dependency                 
app/build.gradle:44 compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.0'

this dependency should be moved to the runtime configuration since it
has no classes warning   unused-dependency                 
app/build.gradle:45 compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.0'

this dependency should be moved to the runtime configuration since it
has no classes warning   unused-dependency                 
app/build.gradle:52 compile
'com.github.gigamole.arcprogressstackview:library:+'

this dependency should be moved to the runtime configuration since it
has no classes warning   unused-dependency                 
app/build.gradle:53 compile 'com.github.dexafree:materiallist:3.2.1'

this dependency should be moved to the runtime configuration since it
has no classes warning   unused-dependency                 
app/build.gradle:54 compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

this dependency should be moved to the runtime configuration since it
has no classes warning   unused-dependency                 
app/build.gradle:55 compile 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.+@aar'

this dependency should be moved to the runtime configuration since it
has no classes warning   unused-dependency                 
app/build.gradle:57 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'

this dependency should be moved to the runtime configuration since it
has no classes warning   unused-dependency                 
app/build.gradle:58 compile 'com.github.shem8:material-login:1.4.0'

this dependency should be moved to the runtime configuration since it
has no classes warning   unused-dependency                 
app/build.gradle:64
compile('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.3.1@aar') {
    transitive = true; }

this dependency should be moved to the runtime configuration since it
has no classes warning   unused-dependency                 
app/build.gradle:74 compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.4'

? app/build.gradle: 11 problems (0 errors, 11 warnings)

To apply fixes automatically, run fixGradleLint, review, and commit
the changes.


BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Should I take the advice? If those dependencies should be in `runtime`, Why does every dependencies wiki/doc don't say that and insist telling us to put dependencies in `compile`?

Edit: I try to take the advice, in other words, change the keyword `compile` to `runtime`, like `runtime 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0'`. However, Android Studio hints that

```
Error:Could not find method runtime() for arguments
[com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0] on object of type
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK
Manager. <a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>
```

So what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I believe `apk` is android for `runtime`, e.g.:

```
apk 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0'
```

Some say `package`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28473873/360211

Maybe both work, maybe there is no difference, maybe there is. I don't know  as very ungoogleable terms.

Answer (score 0):

You should put dependencies that you need for compilation in `compile`, this includes classes you use directly in your sources.

You should put dependencies that you don't need for compilation, but need at runtime in `runtime`, those are not available on the compile classpath, but they will be available at execution.

Comment: Hm, strange. Maybe you should post your `build.gradle`