# Is there a way to load runtime libraries other than put them under src/main/jniLibs?

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, jogl

I am attempting to write an hello triangle for opengl es 2 on Android.

The only working solution I found it to have native jogl libraries under `app/src/main/jniLibs/`, in [this way](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/hello-droid/tree/master/hello-triangle-es2/src/main/jniLibs):

```
app/
 |--> src/
       |--> main/
             |--> jniLibs/
                    |--> lib*.so
```

On my corresponding [hello desktop project](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/helloTriangle), I simply have in my `build.gradle`

```
def joglVersion = '2.3.2'

compile "org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt-main:$joglVersion"
compile "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all-main:$joglVersion"
```

and it work flawless, on runtime, libraries get extracted and provided.

One alternative to this solution is to extract them manually and put them under `project/natives`. They both work.

On android, I never got it working like on the desktop way, a simple `build.gradle`. The only way is, as I said at begin, extract them manually from the jars where they were and put them under `jniLibs/`

No matter wherever I put the plaind directory `natives/android-armv6` (not compress, `.jar` or `.apk`), it always fails:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: org.helloTriangle_es2, PID: 9735
                  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "//natives/android-armv6//libgluegen-rt.so" not found
                      at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:332)
                      at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1069)
                      at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibraryInternal(JNILibLoaderBase.java:624)
                      at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.access$000(JNILibLoaderBase.java:63)
                      at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase$DefaultAction.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.java:106)
                      at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.java:487)
                      at com.jogamp.common.os.DynamicLibraryBundle$GlueJNILibLoader.loadLibrary(DynamicLibraryBundle.java:421)
                      at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform$1.run(Platform.java:317)
                      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:45)
                      at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:287)
                      at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.initSingleton(Platform.java:355)
                      at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.<clinit>(GLProfile.java:147)
                      at org.helloTriangle_es2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6322)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9735 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Looking around, I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28953134/1047713), where they say that basically `apk files` is the (sort of) runtime..

I tried that, adding for :

```
provided files('libs/gluegen-rt-natives-android-armv6.jar')
provided files('libs/jogl-all-natives-android-armv6.jar')
```

but no way. Also trying `compile`/`provided` instead of `provided` made no difference... always the same exception

Am I doing something wrong or extract them manually under `src/main/jniLibs/armeabi` is really the only solution?

Comment: I am a little confused about the different solutions you attempted and what results you got for each one. What happens when you add the `compile` dependency to your build.gradle file?

Comment: I edited the question trying to make it clearer (let me know if it's fine). I basically end up having always the same `UnsatisfiedLinkError` exception